# jQuery click Handler disables play button functionality in audio element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

**EDIT #1 with connexo’s solution**

Within the following HTML, I want to click in the parent `'li'` to play the child `'audio'`

**The problem** is noted in the alert calls within the JS; i.e., trying to compare a HTMLLIElement with a HTMLAudioElement.

How can I successfully do that?

**HTML:**

I have several:

```
<li>
    text here<br>
    <audio controls preload="auto">
    <source src="aSong.mp3">
    </audio>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li:has(audio)').on("click", function(evt) {

    var m, theSongInArray,
    //  thisSong = $(this)[0];  // HTMLLIElement
    //  now a HTMLAudioElement thanks to connexo
        $thisLI = $(this);
        thisSong = $thisLI.find('audio')[0];  

    // itsAllSongs defined elsewhere    
    for (m=0; m < itsAllSongs.length; m++)
    {
        //  HTMLAudioElement
        theSongInArray = itsAllSongs[m];
 
        if (thisSong == theSongInArray)
        {
            if ( thisSong.paused )
                thisSong.play();
            else
            {
                thisSong.pause();
                thisSong.currentTime = 0;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**Note**: connexo's solution is perfect - but now I have a new problem =

My intent above, which connexo has solved, was to be able to click anywhere within `'li:has(audio)'` and have the toggling effect between `.play()` and `.pause()` .. and it now does that.

BUT, now the anywhere within `'li:has(audio)'` seems to **not** include the play icon of:

[image: the standard HTML audio control]

If I click on the slider, the progress bar, the time-stamp, or anywhere else on the long `<audio>` control it works great, but **not** on the play icon on the far left of the above control.

SUPER wierd - this 2nd challenge goes away (I can then click just on the play icon) if I remove:

```
$('li:has(audio)').on("click", function(evt) {

})
```

Hopefully, connexo has another brilliant solution.

**EDIT #2 = solution of the current problem:**

Now, I can click on either the `li` area surrounding the `<audio>` element, or on just the `<audio>` element itself. As a matter of interest, when I click on *just the play icon* of `<audio>`, the song will play and, if I click on the position slider, the *slider will move without playing/pausing the song itself*:

```
/*  
    alert(evt.target);   // = HTMLLIElement, or HTMLAudioElement
*/

if (evt.target.id.length == 0)      
    thisSong = $(this).find('audio')[0];   // HTMLLIElement -> HTMLAudioElement
else   // >= 3, e.g., = "SSB" or "AIRFORCE"
    thisSong = $(this)[0];   // [object HTMLAudioElement]
```

Comment: `thisSong = $(this).find('audio')`

Comment: THANK YOU! Had a brain lapse wrongly thinking ‘li:has(audio)’ was the <audio> element. It’s the <li> element

Comment: I think for your new question we definitely need a runnable example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: You are correct, again. But before I bother you further, I **think** the problem centers on `li:has(audio)` covers the elusive play icon. So, let me marinate on that awhile before I generate a jFiddle.

Comment: Please use a StackOverflow snippet when asking, not an external code representation.

Comment: Sometimes my "slowness" is astronomical. Please see my EDIT at the very bottom of my OP.